# Safely Interupt csv read and write

Tags: csv, go

I am processing csv files, and when I interupt the process, I want to store unprocessed data to another file.

This what I've done

```
csvFile, err := os.Open(csvPath)
r := csv.NewReader(csvFile)

sigc := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
signal.Notify(sigc,
    syscall.SIGHUP,
    syscall.SIGINT,
    syscall.SIGTERM,
    syscall.SIGQUIT)
go func() {
    <-sigc

    savePending(r)
}()

for {
    record, err := r.Read()
    if err == io.EOF {
        break
    }

    if err != nil {
        log.Println(record, err)
        continue
    }

    
    doSomethingWithRecord(record)
}
```

savePending Function

```
func savePending(r *csv.Reader)  {

    pendingFileName := fmt.Sprintf("%s_pending.csv", fileBaseName)
    csvPendingPath := path.Join(dirname, pendingFileName)
    pendingFile, err := os.Create(csvPendingPath)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("Couldn't open the csv file", csvPendingPath, err)
    }
    defer pendingFile.Close()
    pendR := csv.NewWriter(pendingFile)

    records, err := r.ReadAll()
    if err == io.EOF {
        log.Println("no pending records")
    }
    err = pendR.WriteAll(records)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("error writing pending file")
    }
}
```

But when I run the code, then I interupt the script by pressing CTRL+C, I always get panic

```
panic: runtime error: slice bounds out of range [:7887] with capacity 4096

goroutine 82 [running]:
bufio.(*Reader).ReadSlice(0xc0000c2ea0, 0x105930a, 0x88, 0x90, 0xc00090cab0, 0x0, 0x0)
        /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.13.3/libexec/src/bufio/bufio.go:334 +0x232
encoding/csv.(*Reader).readLine(0xc00015c1b0, 0x9, 0x9, 0xc00090cab0, 0xc00090f680, 0x20e)
        /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.13.3/libexec/src/encoding/csv/reader.go:218 +0x49
encoding/csv.(*Reader).readRecord(0xc00015c1b0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc00090cab0, 0x9, 0x9, 0x0, 0x0)
        /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.13.3/libexec/src/encoding/csv/reader.go:266 +0x115
encoding/csv.(*Reader).ReadAll(0xc00015c1b0, 0xc0005af2c0, 0x1000, 0xc0006fc000, 0xc0001da608, 0x0)
        /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.13.3/libexec/src/encoding/csv/reader.go:202 +0x74
main.savePending(0xc00015c1b0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
```

What could be the issue ?

Comment: You're using `csv.Reader` type concurrently (from the main thread and goroutine). Are its methods thread-safe?

Comment: ah correct, think its not thread save

Answer (score 1):

While the `savePending` function is being started, the main routine continues to read from the reader.

How about aborting the for loop on `<-sigc` and saving the rest then:

```golang
csvFile, err := os.Open(csvPath)
r := csv.NewReader(csvFile)

sigc := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
signal.Notify(sigc,
    syscall.SIGHUP,
    syscall.SIGINT,
    syscall.SIGTERM,
    syscall.SIGQUIT)

for {
    select {
    case <-sigc:
        savePending(r)
        return
    default:
    }


    record, err := r.Read()
    if err == io.EOF {
        break
    }

    if err != nil {
        log.Println(record, err)
        continue
    }

    
    doSomethingWithRecord(record)
}
```

Comment: see also https://github.com/golang/go/issues/20280 and https://github.com/jbenet/go-context/blob/master/io/ctxio.go